# Trying to identify this artist signature (Characters identified: 古惠蘭)

Tags: seal

I have looked everywhere and have no solid answer on this signature seal, please help.

[image: art signature identity needed]

Comment: What does the rest of the picture show? If it's a picture of orchids, I don't think that's a name.

Answer (score 1):

It calls "古惠兰"(Chinese simplified). In ancient style of calligraphy large seal script.

"古" means old, ancient.

"惠" means grace,gentle and kindheartedness.

"兰" means orchid.